# Calling the Graph api after SAML2.0 auth. How do I get the Auth token required

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, saml-2.0

Our web aap is authenticating with the Azure AD via SAML2.0 similar to [this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-on-protocol-reference%20description)

In return we get SAML assertion(SAML token).

But when the user who logs in have more then 150+ groups the response doesn't contain the group information(so that token size doesn’t exceed HTTP header size limits. More info on [this](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/))

But what it return is a Graph Api to be hit to get the group information something like https://graph.windows.net/{tenant id}/users/{user id}/getMemberObject.

By going through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview)

I understand that I need to attach a Auth bearer token with the http request to hit the graph api successfully. 
My problem is how do I get the Auth bearer token?
How can I use the SAML token to get the Auth bearer token?

Other useful link - [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#claims-in-idtokens) [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations)

Answer (score 1):

I've only used the non SAML graph API using the [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD) libraries but from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims) it appears the `NameID` seems to be the basis for requesting an access token for the Graph API:

```
<Subject>
  <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">m_H3naDei2LNxUmEcWd0BZlNi_jVET1pMLR6iQSuYmo</NameID>
  <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer" />
</Subject>
```

From this [post](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/11/19/oauth2-with-saml2.html),

> "Here the Client gets a SAML bearer assertion from the SAML Identity
>   Provider then requests an access token from the Authorisation Server
>   using the SAML bearer assertion as proof of identity"

and this [article](http://meuslivros.github.io/OAuth-2-0-Identity-and-Access-Management-Patterns/OEBPS/ch09s03.html) states the entire `Assertion` is used to get the access token, where you:

> encode the whole assertion by using base64url encoding before adding
>   it as part of the POST request

Comment: I also noticed the NameId part , but you can change the name id format `<Subject>
            <NameID 
                Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">Abhishek@xxx.com
            </NameID>` Wondering would a access toke be as simple as my email id?

Comment: Thanks for digging in, really appreciate that. If I get you correct,  since I have SAML assertion, I need to exchange that with the auth token by hitting the `oauth2/token` api of microsoft. This left us with the questions, what's the exact api and parameters and whether it supports SAML assertions [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) gives more information about the api and parameters but doesn't confirm whether it accepts SAML assertions or not. Any pointers on this?

Comment: The link you have is for OBOF, for two APIs talking to each other. What you asked for was how to access the graph API on behalf of the user. For that you just need an access token. The second article in the answer says to POST the base 64 encoded SAML Assertion to the oauth2/token (it actually says oauth/token but I checked my openid version of the code and the latest version uses oauth2/token). If the other end supports SAML then it will return the access token and you use that to query the graph API to get the user's groups for example

Comment: hi @AbhishekAgarwal, Have you resolved this issue? I am also facing this. The saml response contains "getMemberObject" api. I don't know how to call it by using saml token.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that exchanging a SAML token for a Graph access token is only supported for AD FS, not Azure AD. As per:

> This scenario works only when AD FS is the federated identity provider that issued the original SAMLv1 token. You cannot exchange a SAMLv2 token issued by Azure AD for a Microsoft Graph access token.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion.

In general, you have to add the OIDC/OAuth stack to your app. As I understand it, this is in addition to your existing SAML authentication implementation. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-token-exchange-saml-oauth