# Get profile picture of user in Azure AD via SAML

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, saml

I am using Azure AD with SAML in my application so that the users to login via SSO via Azure AD.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-enterprise-apps-manage-sso

I have no issue implementing the Single Sign-on and fetch the attributes (First name, Last name etc.) which I have set as claims in Azure AD portal.

[image]

My requirement is to fetch the profile image of the user too.

Unfortunately, I was not able to locate the attributes which I need to set in the claims of Azure AD.

I tried searching the following properties: user.thumb, user.thumnailPhoto, user.avatar, user.displayPicture, user.profilePicture but none of the properties exists there to add it as a claim.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to get profile image added in Azure AD portal as claims while logging via SAML?

Comment: You should be using graph to get the image. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUserThumbnailPhoto

Comment: @maweeras I am getting all other necessary fields except by Azure AD as claims but not the image. Do they even support giving an url of thumb in claims?

Comment: you dont need a URL. Because if you know user details you can construct a request to retrieve via graph the user photo. Claims are not efficient method for relaying 10Kb-100KB worth of binary/jpeg payloads.

Comment: This may be dumb but how do I get access token via claims so that I can prepare the url to fetch the profile image.

Comment: I've been discussing getting access token for the graph API from a SAML Assertion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488921/calling-the-graph-api-after-saml2-0-auth-how-do-i-get-the-auth-token-required/49490786

Comment: Let's see if we get some solution.